# in one profiles.yml file, can have multiple profiles?

Tags: dbt

can we have two profile in one profiles.yml file in root

For example, to have a profile for Azure Blob and another profile for Azure Synapse SQL

for info:

- dbt version: 1.3.1
- python version: 3.9.6
- adapter = dbt-synapse

```yaml
# profiles.yml

default: dbt_project

dbt_project:
  target: dev
  outputs:
    dev:
      type: synapse  
      driver: 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' # (The ODBC Driver installed on your system)
      server: XXXXXXX
      database: ###
      port: 1433
      schema: #######
      user: ######
      password: #####


azure_blob:
  target: dev
  outputs:
      dev:
        type: azure_blob
        account_name: ##
        account_key: ##
        container: ##
        prefix: delta_lake
```

when i r deb-debug
get this error

02:25:37  Encountered an error:
Runtime Error :  dbt encountered an error while trying to read your profiles.yml file.

the error starting on line azure_blob:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [multiple profiles in one profiles.yml is possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75286648/multiple-profiles-in-one-profiles-yml-is-possible)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `outputs:` line under `azure_blob` is indented when it shouldn't be.  If you unindent this line you should be good. Make it look like:

```yaml
azure_blob:
  target: dev
  outputs:
    dev:
      type: azure_blob
      account_name: ##
      account_key: ##
      container: ##
      prefix: delta_lake
```

(P.S, there is a typo in the start of your file `defaul` should be `default`.)

Comment: I changed /corrected.. but still the same error

Comment: Need assistance in this

Comment: @mxendire it appears you have a separate, unrelated issue that might best be posed as a separate question.